# Conversion of laplacian form cartesian to spherical coordinates 2nd part

Tags: spherical-coordinates, laplacian

Using the same method of [conversion of laplacian from cartesian to spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391131/conversion-of-laplacian-from-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinates) and changing $\psi$ to $u$, I am trying to finish the demostration of the spherical laplacian. However, I have a problem, as after adding up $\frac{\delta^{2}u}{\delta x^{2}}+\frac{\delta^{2}u}{\delta y^{2}}+\frac{\delta^{2}u}{\delta z^{2}}$
for the part of $u=u(\theta)$, which is the last I need to calculate.

I have:
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta \theta^{2}}-\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta}\frac{2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)}{r^2}+\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta}\frac{cos(\theta)}{r^2 sin(\theta)} $$ 
where I should have:
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta \theta^{2}}+\frac{cos(\theta)}{r^2 sin(\theta)}\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta}$$

**As you can see, in what I have done I had an extra term**
$$-\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta}\frac{2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)}{r^2}$$

**I don't know if I have to simplify more or I have derived badly. I request aid on this problem**

I had derived 
$$\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}= \frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta} \frac{cos(\theta)cos(\phi)}{r} $$
$$\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}= \frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta} \frac{cos(\theta)sin(\phi)}{r} $$
$$\frac{\delta u}{\delta z}= \frac{\delta u}{\delta\theta} \frac{-sin(\theta)}{r} $$
And my problem maybe in calculating:
$$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta x^2}= \frac{\delta}{\delta x}(\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta} \frac{cos(\theta)cos(\phi)}{r} )$$
$$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta y^2}= \frac{\delta}{\delta y}(\frac{\delta u}{\delta \theta} \frac{cos(\theta)sin(\phi)}{r})$$
$$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta z^2}= \frac{\delta}{\delta z}(\frac{\delta u}{\delta\theta} \frac{-sin(\theta)}{r})$$

**I had simplified as they do in [conversion of laplacian from cartesian to spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391131/conversion-of-laplacian-from-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinates) at the end of the question, so try to give the answer in cosines and sines, please.**
Thank you.

Comment: Phoneheads, is that [you again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702210/laplacian-in-polar-coordinates-in-one-dimension) under a new name? Try to use a single account, please.

Comment: Ey, i am not that guy XD

Comment: I, at least have done something and I thought about what i have done

Comment: And why do you think I am that guy, uh? I read what he did, and he didn't thought.

Comment: Come on @AlexM. , you understand this and  I have written the link from where I started, can you help?

Comment: @AlexM. no, i'm not