# How to convert the Laplacian from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, laplacian

The Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates is :
$$\nabla^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}$$

And the Laplacian in spherical polar coordinates is :
$$\nabla^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}}+\frac{1}{\tan \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{\sin ^{2} \theta} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \phi^{2}}\right)$$

I am really sorry if this is a dumb question but I am a mathematics beginner and I am facing a problem. How do we convert the Laplacian from Cartesian coordinates to spherical polar coordinates? There is literally no derivation given in my book as to how it came. Can someone please provide the derivation? Please help. I am really confused.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586848/how-to-obtain-the-gradient-in-polar-coordinates This might help! The only difference is, is that your question is about the 3D coordinates instead of the 2D coordinates, but the calculation is analagous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conversion of laplacian from cartesian to spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391131/conversion-of-laplacian-from-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinates)

Comment: See also the link above.

Comment: You could use the expressions for the gradient and the divergence in spherical coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

The question is extremely interesting, and to be properly answered it would require notions of Riemannian geometry (that I may add later) that probably are a bit too sophisticated. In any case, one can do the following for the 2 dimensional case (the 3d can be found here https://planetmath.org/DerivationOfTheLaplacianFromRectangularToSphericalCoordinates):

Recall that Laplace's equation in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in terms of the usual (i.e., Cartesian) $(x, y)$ coordinate system is:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=u_{x x}+u_{y y}=0
$$

The Cartesian coordinates can be represented by the polar coordinates as follows:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=r \cos \theta \\
y=r \sin \theta
\end{array}\right.
$$

Let us first compute the partial derivatives of $x, y$ w.r.t. $r, \theta$ :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos \theta, & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-r \sin \theta \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\sin \theta, & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=r \cos \theta
\end{array}\right.
$$

To do so, let's compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ first. We will use the Chain Rule since $(x, y)$ are functions of $(r, \theta)$ as shown above.

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} &=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos \theta+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin \theta \quad \text { using } \\
&=\cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{aligned}

Now, let's compute $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}$. Noticing that both $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ are functions of $(x, y)$

we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}} &=\cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
&=\cos \theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)+\sin \theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right) \\
&=\cos ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+2 \cos \theta \sin \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+\sin ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, let's compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \theta^{2}}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} &=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\
&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(-r \sin \theta)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(r \cos \theta) \\
&=-r \sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+r \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{aligned}
$$

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \theta^{2}}=&-r \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-r \sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-r \sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+r \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
=&-r \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-r \sin \theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\right)-r \sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+r \cos \theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\right) \\
=&-r \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-r \sin \theta\left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}(-r \sin \theta)+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y} r \cos \theta\right) \\
&-r \sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+r \cos \theta\left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}(-r \sin \theta)+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}} r \cos \theta\right) \\
=&-r\left(\cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+r^{2}\left(\sin ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-2 \cos \theta \sin \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+\cos ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{aligned}

Dividing both sides by $r^{2}$ and using the equation above, we have
$$
\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \theta^{2}}=-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\sin ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-2 \cos \theta \sin \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+\cos ^{2} \theta \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}
$$
Finally, adding the last two, using the obvious relation $\cos ^{2} \theta+\sin ^{2} \theta=1$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \theta^{2}}=-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}
$$
which can be cleaned up as:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \theta^{2}}
$$
Hence, Laplace's equation becomes:
$$
u_{x x}+u_{y y}=u_{r r}+\frac{1}{r} u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} u_{\theta \theta}=0
$$

Comment: The question was about *spherical* coordinates...

Comment: As I wrote above, I gave a reference for all the details in spherical coordinates and added here the case of polar coordinates to have a glimpse of the (similar) calculations, hope tot may be helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't notice the link at the beginning.